# Do spells halving movement stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, stacking

If a group of monsters were, say, *Slow*ed and then subjected to *Sickening radiance* would their speed be one-half normal, or one-fourth?

*Slow* has, in part:

> An affected target’s speed is halved...

A monster who fails their *Sickening radiance* saving throw:

> ...suffers one level of exhaustion...

...which will halve its speed when the second level of exhaustion is reached.

Effects don't stack with themselves, but I'm unclear if the halving of speed is the effect, or if different sources of speed halving will apply together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes

From the rules:

> **Combining Magical Effects**
>
> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of
> those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple
> times don’t combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as
> the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations
> overlap.
>
> For example, if two clerics cast bless on the same target, that
> character gains the spell’s benefit only once; he or she doesn’t get
> to roll two bonus dice.

Any effects from different sources stack. The only exception is when the rules state otherwise (generally when there is no stacking to be done). For example, multiple effects causing advantage or disadvantage won't stack.